# In Mac OS X how to define the thumbnail for a specific file type?

Tags: macos, thumbnails, finder

I have many files with the file extension ".dat". I wish to assign  a thumbnail to these files with this extension because the default one is of very low resolution and is disturbing when working. I figured how to change the thumbnail for specific, single files, but I would like to define the file type for all .dat files.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simple, in the application you're developing, in the dictionary for that document type in your app's Info.plist (if there is no such dict, add that first), you add in the [`CFBundleTypeIconFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) key the name of an icns file in your app resources that provides the icon and…

Oh, wait, you mean, how to do so as a user? As soon as that question is moved to Ask Different, I'll be able to answer that, short of creating a dummy app for that sole purpose (EDIT:) or modifying the source icon in the system or the app to which .dat belongs, which may be used for more than one type and is risky business anyway (END EDIT), I am not aware of any way you can do so.

Comment: How unfortunate. Well then... thanks anyway.

Would it help to know what the system is doing in the background when I change the thumbnail icon manually? Could it be scripted? Still, new .dat files would probably get the old thumbnail.

Comment: When you set a custom icon for a file, it gets added to the file metadata. Oh, BTW, I edited the answer slightly.